# jQuery function wrong Product id at the second click.

Tags: jquery, events, tabs

I have a product page with some cheese. When I'm returning at the main list that work at the first click, but at the second return the first cheese of the list. number one.

Do you think Is something to do with the `api.seekTo`?
How can I get the right ID every time? is the code wrong somewhere?

```
productsList.find('a[href*="#"]') // find all hashed cheese url's
        .click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var cheeseHash = this.hash;
            productsList.hide(200, function() {
                // -1 important (ties in with flash zoomed-in product images)
                api.seekTo(parseInt(cheeseHash.replace(/#/, ''), 10)  - 1);
            });
            return false;
        });


    $('#allProducts').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        callToActionscript('asjs', 0);
        window.location.hash = '';
        $('#products').fadeOut(10, function(e) {
            var listWidth = productsList.fadeIn(400).width();
            productsList.css({width: listWidth, marginLeft: '-' + (listWidth / 2) + 'px', left: '50%'});
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can't see anything wrong.. can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: You mean http://www.castellocheese.co.uk/products and sorry, couldn't find what's causing this problem - add debug (alerts or Console.log) in key places in your code until you find something suspicious.

Comment: yes,thanks, I'll give a go. I think is something to do with:
api.seekTo(parseInt(cheeseHash.replace(/#/, ''), 10)  - 1);

Comment: Look more into where you determine what placeholder to show or maybe your `cheese` array.

Comment: fix it myself mate, sorry. It was the fading in on out.

Comment: Interesting.. please post what you did in order to solve this as new Answer then Accept it to mark this question resolved then. :)